# Logout user by sending them to a Logout Webview

Tags: react-native, expo, shopify

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to log out both the user on the expo app as well as logging them out from the `react-native-webview`.

The user can log out of the `expo` app by pressing logout (which just handles the auth logic), however; the user is still logged in inside the `webview` (which is the shop uri).

At the moment, I came up with two possible ways: either set `incognito` to true on the webview, or send the user to a `Screen` which returns another `webview` to the shopify's `logout` uri.

```js
// sending user to shopify logout webview

//navigator
<Stack.Navigator>
 <Stack.Screen
   name="AccountDetails"
   component={AccountDetailsScreen}
  />

 <Stack.Screen
  name="ShopWebview"
  component={ShopWebview}
 />

  <Stack.Screen
    name="LogOut"
    component={LogOutWebView}
    />
</Stack.Navigator>


// from `AccountDetails` component, user presses handleLogout()

const handleLogOut = () => navigation.navigate('LogOut');

// shopify logout webview

export const LogOutWebView = () => {
  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: 'https://www.quarantotto.co.jp/account/logout' }}
    />
  );
};
```

This seems to work w/ android, but it doesn't seem to work on iOS? I'm not quite sure why that is.

I can still set the `incognito` to true likeso:

```js
// ShopWebview

<WebView
  incognito
  source={{ uri: 'someshop.com/' }}
/>
```

and this would help me not store the logged in user's session, but not quite sure if this is the proper way to handle auth.

If I can use the first method of sending the user to a webview that handles logout when a user visits it, that would be great. But not sure why it's not working from ios.

any ideas?

#### UPDATE: possible working solution?

Whenever the user logs out, they are sent back to a screen w/ `login or register`.

The issue was that whenever the user pressed `login`, since their session was cached, they are redirect to their account screen (which is what I don't want since if a user presses logout, I want them to be `logged out` and have to log back in).

what I have done is just inject some js in the `LoginWebview`

```js
const handleNavigationStateChange = (newNavState) => {
  if (webViewRef.current) {
      webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(scriptFetchCustomer());
  }

  
  if (newNavState.url.includes('logout')) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const redirectTo = `window.location = "${someshop.com/login}"`;
        webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(redirectTo);
      }, 500);
    }
  };
```

seems to work, but I don't enjoy using the settimeout. any recommendations?

#### second update... doesn't work on android

Android isn't working properly. I've set the source to the shopify's `/account/logout` uri, but inside `handleNavigationStateChange` the `newNavState`'s url isn't the `logout` as it's set on the `source`.

....

#### Last update:

It finally works as I wanted to. I had to check for the url changes inside `onNavigationStateChange` of the webview. Then I could do what I wanted. I basically sent user to `/account/logout`, then set current `logged in user state` back into null which fires a redirect to login screen.

Hope it helps someone.